# payex cancel button refreshes the pages even after sending cancelUrl

Tags: php, redirect, payment-gateway, payment

The payment flow is working fine. The payment failed and success are working properly. But the cancel button in the payment page just refreshes the page(well redirects to some payex pages and again loads to payment page. I have check the domain of the redirected url, its just payex domain, never my website domain). It works fine after the payment. After payment it goes to my domain url and works fine.

When I send blank in canceUrl, it doesnt show cancel button. Which is working fine according to payex documentaion. But when I send cancelUrl it shows cancel button but does not redirect to the url I send it redirects to payex url and again loads payment page.

I need to show cancel button and redirect to my website page.

I am using two step redirect model of the payex. I am using php in my serverside.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in my code. This might help somebody else. I had used some unnecessary values in additionalValues parameter while creating the order. Removing it solved my problem.

Comment: how did you implement Payex. I am trying to implement it in my wordpress project but to no success.